# $cookies return null when use inside a factory after redirect on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

$cookies return null when use inside a factory after redirect on angularjs. Here is my controller code where i store the cookies.

```
    // Visitor to the cookies
    $cookieStore.put('visitor_name', $scope.name);

    $cookieStore.put('visitor_email', $scope.email);

    $cookieStore.put('visitor_message', $scope.message);
```

After redirect to  $location.path('/client');

factory.establishUser = function() {

```
var data = {
    command: "establishUser",
    reqtype: "Client", //Operator or Client
    token: 'token issued',
    data: {
        userinfo: {
            token: "token",
            id: '53d4d7dda9e70788118b4567',
            hasvisited: true,
            email: $cookies.visitor_email,
            name: $cookies.visitor_name,
            usertype: "Client",
            status: "Open",
            socketkey: "socketkey"
        }
    }
};
```

$cookies.visitor_email and $cookies.visitor_name returns null.

Comment: have you checked browser dev tools, for cookies, are they getting stored?

Comment: Yes they are ,but you have to hit refresh icon..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on redirect. Default implementation of cookies in Angular is storing cookie with 'path' of current location, not the root one. Currently there is no way to change this using $cookieStore.

For more information please see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1786).

UPDATE: According to the issue, it has been fixed and closed in 1.3.x branch.

Comment: Do you mean that $cookies are only save on specific path?

Comment: Yes, if you are on '/somewhere/something/', cookie would be saved under this path only. So if you redirect user to '/other/something/', the cookies would not work for this path.
The only way they would work for you is using path '/' (assuming you are on the same domain). Angular implementation does not allow to change path at all.

Comment: I save the cookie from here /prototypes/html/visitor# , and redirect to /prototypes/html/visitor#/client and i get null.. I have to refresh my page in order to get the real value.